# Opening (c)tags in new tab in (G)Vim

Tags: vim

Ctrl+w Ctrl+i and :stj is nice, but how do I jump to a tag (under the cursor) in a new tab in GVim/Vim?

Comment: A supercharged superset of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539231/how-to-use-multiple-tabs-when-tagging-to-a-function-in-vim : open on new tab only if in another file, and when closing the new tab jump back to the parent.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Similar question [How to use multiple tabs when tagging to a function in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539231/how-to-use-multiple-tabs-when-tagging-to-a-function-in-vim)

It points out [this wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_every_buffer_in_its_own_tabpage) ([which points back at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vimctags-tips-and-tricks)) with these settings (seems to work ok in terminal, haven't tried gvim):

```
"--------------------
" Function: Open tag under cursor in new tab
" Source:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vimctags-tips-and-tricks
"--------------------
map <C-\> :tab split<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
"--------------------
" Function: Remap keys to make it more similar to firefox tab functionality
" Purpose:  Because I am familiar with firefox tab functionality
"--------------------
map     <C-T>       :tabnew<CR>
map     <C-N>       :!gvim &<CR><CR>
map     <C-W>       :confirm bdelete<CR>
```

Comment: That first link contained the magical `nmap <C-Enter> <C-w><C-]><C-w>T` which was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This is really nice, but it *always* opens a new tab. What if the file is already opened in another tab? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @OlivierPons See my answer on this post to get it to reuse existing tabs: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10014/navigate-to-tag-in-a-new-tab-if-not-already-opened-like-tab-drop/10320#10320

Answer (score 1):

You can also open tags in preview `:ptag` with `C-w}`

Answer (score 0):

You can easy jump to tag in a new tab like this

```
<c-w>gf open in a new tab (Ctrl-w gf)
```

Also, you can open it in a split view:

```
<c-w>f  open in a new window (Ctrl-w f)
```

Check this - http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor