# Jump to definition in new tab

Tags: vim, ctags

What i'm looking for is the following behaviour:

- `^]`
  Should open the definition below the cursor in a new **tab** instead of a new buffer and reuse already open tabs
- `^O`
  Should switch back to the previous location in the previous tab instead of switching the buffer of the current tab to the previous locations buffer
- `^I`
  Should behave accordingly

I tried

```
:set switchbuf=newtab
```

as well as

```
:set switchbuf=usetab
```

but both did not change any of the behaviour.

Comment: You can find some inspiration here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_every_buffer_in_its_own_tabpage

Comment: Whoevery voted to close this: wrong. The consensus is that Vim/Emacs questions are *on-topic* here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening (c)tags in new tab in (G)Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908269/opening-ctags-in-new-tab-in-gvim)

Answer (score 9):

Look here:

[vim: Open tag in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069279/vim-open-tag-in-new-tab/6069388#6069388)

Basically, the idea is to do <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>C-]</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> -- and then map that behaviour to the keys you like.

Comment: Sry, I don't (yet) know how achive the inverse effect with `^O`.. looking into it

Comment: The problem with this solution is also that it does not reuse tabs, even with switchbuf=usetab

Comment: To fix the reuse tab problem see my post here: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10014/navigate-to-tag-in-a-new-tab-if-not-already-opened-like-tab-drop/10320#10320

Comment: @barbaz Just a heads-up for you ^

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin that not only jump tag in new tab but also jump back to the correct tab when you press < C-t > to jump back.
https://github.com/ipod825/TagJump

Comment: Please, add context around your link so that your answer would remain useful in case the linked site goes down