# vim: Open tag in new tab

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there a plugin or script to open ctags entries in a new tab? I'd like to put my cursor over a function, press <kbd>ctrl+]</kbd> and have the entry open in another tab. I'd also like if I visually select an entry, for <kbd>ctrl+]</kbd> to still work and open in a new vim tab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening (c)tags in new tab in (G)Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908269/opening-ctags-in-new-tab-in-gvim)

Comment: @richq I tried the top voted solution in my .vimrc and it didn't do anything when pressing ctrl+\.

Comment: fair enough, I should have used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539231 as the dupe, as that does contain sehe's answer too. I wonder if <C-\> works for anything? It mixes Control and <Leader> and probably just confuses vim.

Comment: I use `<C-\>` to toggle NERDTree. You can totally map `<C-\>` :)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can

<kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>C-]</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

To achieve that effect

Then you can also map that:

```
:nnoremap <silent><Leader><C-]> <C-w><C-]><C-w>T
```

**Edit:** *also, depending on what you actually want, don't forget you can open tags in preview (`:ptag`) with e.g. <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>. Just mentioning it in case...*

Comment: sadly, if the tag operation halts for any reason, this doesn't work. For example, if there are multiple tags and I have to pick between them. Any solution?

Comment: @uɐɾɹɐʇ ןnɐd: that will depend on your definition of `<C-w><C-]>` - with me it appears to always jump to the tag with highest prio without asking (as documented). Perhaps you have interfering mappings, see `:verbose map <C-w>`, `:verbose imap <C-w>` etc

Comment: It breaks when the tag jump fails for some reason or another. Maybe there are multiple files I have to choose from, or the file is open in another buffer. Any ideas how to deal with that?

Comment: @uɐɾɹɐʇ ןnɐd: what I said in my previous comment... [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#CTRL-]); Did you try mapping ex commands, instead of `normal mode` commands? [You could use `:stag!`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#tag-!) instead, [or even `:silent! stag!`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:silent). Tip: Sneak in ex commands in a `insert mode` mapping [using `<C-o>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-O)

Comment: :nnoremap <silent><Leader><C-]> <C-w><C-]><C-w>T is not working for me so tried :nnoremap <C-]> <C-w><C-]><C-w>T its working but the arrow keys misbehaves can you help me on this

Comment: @PaulTarjan What about having the mapping press <C-w>g<C-]><C-w>T instead? That solves the problem if there are multiple tags, but not if there is no tag

Comment: This is awesome. One issue I found was that you jump to a new tab no matter what, even if the definition is in the current tab. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @JakeByman not readily. Perhaps `:tj` with `:se switchbuf=useopen,usetab` could be a start (but I haven't tried. I use YouCompleteMe for 90% navigation of navigation tasks, and when jumping inside a file will just use `C-]`)

Comment: Boom! The `set switchbuf=useopen/usetab` did the trick! You're my favorite, this is gamechanging

Comment: It's a combination of two sequences, `:help CTRL-W_]` and `:help CTRL-W_T`.

Comment: This mapping freezes my vim.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two pretty ad-hoc mappings (in case your tags are generated by `ctags`):

```
nnoremap <C-]> :tabnew %<CR>g<C-]>
vnoremap <C-]> <Esc>:tabnew %<CR>gvg<C-]>
```

First we open current buffer in a new tab; then we try to jump to a tag under cursor (`g<C-]>`, which is equal to `:tjump`, jumps to the tag directly if there's only one match, or provides a list of matches if there are many).

Pros:

- "[works on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes/58780#58780)" ©

Cons:

- if you exit from list of matches without choosing any of them, the newly created tab will remain open
- the same happens if there are no matches at all

P.S. Could you provide a use case for visual mode mapping?

P.P.S. If you generate tags with [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) (which is better than `ctags`) and use its [vim mappings](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim), replace the above mappings with the following ones:

```
nnoremap <C-]> :tabnew %<CR><C-]>
vnoremap <C-]> <Esc>tabnew %<CR>gv<C-]>
```

Comment: For visual mode mapping, our codebase has some classes in them named `foo:bar:baz` but my ctags breaks on `:` since I don't want to select `foo::bar` as one entity. So I usually go into visual mode over `foo:bar:baz` to jump to it.

Comment: I see. So have these mappings helped? The commands used in them are pretty general, so hopefully they work everywhere without conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody is still looking for a solution. On this solution when no tag is found no more blank tab will be left.

```
function! w:GoToTag(tagWord)

    let l:tagfile = &tags
    :tabe
    execute 'set tags=' . l:tagfile
    execute ':silent tjump ' . a:tagWord

    let l:tagFilename = expand('%:t')

    if l:tagFilename == ''
        :tabclose
        :tabprevious
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a keyboard shortcut, 'g' followed by CONTROL-], in ~/.vimrc as follows:

```
nmap g<C-]> :execute 'tab tag '.expand('<cword>')<CR>

nmap       means 'when in normal mode'
g<C-j>     is the shortcut, 'g' followed by CTRL-]
execute    is a means of executing a command passed as a string
tab tag    means "open a new tab and run 'ta'"
expand     is used to expansion of a vim item
<cword>    means a word the same as used for '*'. See also <cWORD>
```

You can test "tab ta" via :tab tag *functionname*

Comment: I tried everything...only solution that worked with NERDTreeTabsToggle. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: And if you use `~/.vim` instead of `~/.vimrc` then put the line in a file called `~/.vim/plugin/ctags.vim` or similar.