# vim using "cscope find s" command and open result in new tab instead of window

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin, cscope

I use cscope command `:cs find s someFunction` and i see the long list with this function appearance, I find that I'm interested in list and open it, vim opens a file in a new window, I want to open file in a new tab.

I found several similar questions, but they did not help. For example:

[vim: Open tag in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069279/vim-open-tag-in-new-tab)

how i can open open new tab from cscope list of tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `:tab` command redirects split windows into split tabs. Just prefix your `:cs` command with it:

```
:tab cs find s someFunction
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it.